# Restored/updated Nuget packages insist on being source-controlled by TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, nuget

When I do a nuget package restore (or just update packages) in a Visual Studio 2012 solution, all the newly downloaded packages show up in `Team Explorer >> Pending Changes >> Included Files`. This is *despite* an entry in my root `.tfignore` file that suppresses anything in my packages directory (set up after I added `repositories.config` to source control).

The workaround -- simple but annoying to have to do each time -- is to simply do an `undo` on the `packages` directory in `Pending Changes` and all the package files then disappear from `Pending Changes` completely. (As a check, at that point I can then comment out the entry in `.tfignore` and `Pending Changes >> Excluded Files >> Detected` immediately reports these as unversioned files; reinstating the `.tfignore` entry hides them from the `Detected` count.)

I found one [probable fix](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/10/17/tell-tfs-not-to-add-nuget-packages-to-source-control) that makes use of cloaked folders and should make the annoyance go away for good, but why doesn't the `.tfignore` entry suffice?